# SQL Server: "Script table as..." in SSMS shows wrong column widths

Tags: sql, ssms, sql-server-2016

This is weird - so weird I haven't even been able to search for it effectively.

We're migrating schema and code changes to a database belonging to a new customer.  We've trying to script some tables out of Object Explorer by right-clicking the table and selecting "Script table as...".

The script that we get is several generations out of date, and doesn't match what we get if we use sp_help.

There are two columns that are really causing a problem.  If I use `sp_help`, the columns are defined as 70 and 30 characters long.  This is the current length.

```
MEMBER_LAST_NAME   nvarchar no  70  yes (n/a)  (n/a)  Latin1_General_BIN
MEMBER_FIRST_NAME  nvarchar no  30  yes (n/a)  (n/a)  Latin1_General_BIN
```

But if I **script** the table, the lengths are cut in half:

```
[MEMBER_LAST_NAME] [nvarchar](35) NULL,
[MEMBER_FIRST_NAME] [nvarchar](15) NULL,
```

Now, it's likely that the columns were originally defined as 35 and 15, and then altered later.  But if we script out the table, why doesn't it show the current column widths?

Unfortunately, we're using a third-party migration utility that appears to rely on "script as", so we're assigning the wrong widths.  Any ideas welcome.

Answer (score 0):

try this option right click database and select task, then select generate the script. follow the steps as per wizard and generate the script for the object which you need.

Comment: Interesting idea, but it returns the same results as "script as...":